# MySQL Query To Select Post By Postmeta

Tags: post-meta, mysql, wpdb

I have two custom post types, *type1* and *type2*. *Type2* posts have a postmeta called *postID* that is the ID number of a post in *type1*. When showing *type1* in single.php I want a mysql query that selects the *type2* post.

The only data I have is the ID number of *type1*. So I have to select from *type2* postmeta where the meta_key = postID and the meta_value = *type1* ID. I then need to use the post_id of that row to select the post from wp_posts.

I'm not good with forming mysql queries, so is there a single query that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question you are trying to show both post on single.php something like this should work as a second loop.

Put This INSIDE the first loop. Do this so you can get the current post ID

```
$parent_id=the_ID();

// Second Loop
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'TYPE1', 'meta_key' => $parent_id ) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
//normal loop stuff such as the_content();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```